# unexpected kawrgs ,TypeError at /courses/course/1/1/

Tags: python, django

I'm getting type error for the pk.
Something like:

step_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' for the second one in /courses/course/1/1, where as it has been taken care in the following method of step_detail. What am I doing wrong?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Course, Step


def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html', {'courses': courses})


def course_detail(request, pk):
    # course=Course.objects.get(pk=pk)
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'courses/course_detail.html', {'course': course})


def step_detail(request, course_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, course_id=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
    return render(request, 'courses/step_detail.html', {'step': step})
```

And the url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list),
    url(r'(?P<course_pk>\d+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.step_detail),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.course_detail),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2 different variable names:

- `pk` in `urls.py`
- `step_pk` in `views.py`

You should use the same name.

Comment: No problem, an accept would be appreciated for the answer.